# Can't start twilio video chat - Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twilio

I'm trying to setup a video chat between 2 people using Twilio's video api in a Rails project.
But I can't figure out how to "Initiate" this on client side. I hoped to do this with a connect_to_room.js.erb file & put it in a specified div.

This is the controller code:

```
  def connect_to_room
    @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(ENV['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID'], ENV["TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN"])
    @room = @client.video.rooms.create
    @sid = @room.sid
    new_key = @client.new_keys.create
    @access_token = Twilio::JWT::AccessToken.new(ENV['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID'], new_key.sid, new_key.secret)
    @access_token_jwt = @access_token.to_jwt
  end
```

Comment: Roman, did you find an answer ? I am in the same position.

Comment: Nah Alok, I'm sorry.